# SQL Inner Join consulta multiple y mostrar el registro con el valor maximo

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un inconveniente con una de mis consultas , le e estado moviendo de diferentes maneras pero no he dado con el correcto , tal vez sea sencillo , explico un poco , la consulta trae información de 4 tablas diferentes por ejemplo:

```
-Tabla ENT_PERFIL_EMP : trae campo Nombre y valida campo puesto con tabla ENT_PERFILES.
-Tabla ENT_PERFILES : trae doc_nombre.
-Tabla ENT_DOCS: trae revision_actual, descripcion, ultima_mod, categoria.
-Tabla ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO: trae fecha_ent , revision.
```

la consulta es esta, si me muestra lo que necesito mas sin embargo en la tabla ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO se alojan todos los registros de ENT por lo cual necesito traerme solamente el máximo de la columna Revision, utilize MAX(Revision) me funciono una vez pero le agregue otro dato y ya no me funciono.

```
select ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Nombre,ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre as 'Nombre Documento',ENT_DOCS.Descripcion,ENT_PERFILES.Categoria,ENT_DOCS.Revision_actual as 'Revision actual documento',max(Revision) as 'Revision Entrenamiento',ENT_DOCS.Ultima_mod as 'Fecha Ultima Revision',ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO.Fecha_ent as 'Fecha Entrenamiento',DATEDIFF(DAY,ENT_DOCS.Ultima_mod,GETDATE()) as 'Dias Transcurridos',ENT_DOCS.[Status] from ENT_PERFIL_EMP left join ENT_PERFILES on ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Puesto=ENT_PERFILES.Puesto left join ENT_DOCS on ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre=ENT_DOCS.Doc_nombre left join ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO on ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre=ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO.Doc_nombre where ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Num_emp='15483' and ENT_DOCS.[Status]='Actual' group by ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Nombre,ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre,ENT_DOCS.Descripcion,ENT_PERFILES.Categoria,ENT_DOCS.Revision_actual,ENT_DOCS.Ultima_mod,ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO.Fecha_ent,ENT_DOCS.[Status] order by Categoria,ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre asc
```

En la imagen se puede ver como me trae ambos registros de l campo revision entrenamiento , yo solo necesitaría traerme el máximo en este caso seria el registro con el numero 13.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigos lo e resuelto , no puedo escribir el query final porque me paso de los caracteres permitidos pero lo puedo compartir.

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví modificando un poco el query.......

```
select ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Nombre,ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre,ENT_DOCS.Descripcion,ENT_PERFILES.Categoria,ENT_DOCS.Status,ENT_DOCS.Ultima_mod,DATEDIFF(DAY,ENT_DOCS.Ultima_mod,GETDATE()) as 'Dias Transcurridos',ENT_DOCS.Revision_actual,MAX(Revision) as 'Revision Entrenamiento' from ENT_PERFIL_EMP inner join ENT_PERFILES on ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Puesto=ENT_PERFILES.Puesto inner join ENT_DOCS on ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre=ENT_DOCS.Doc_nombre left join ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO on ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre=ENT_ENTRENAMIENTO.Doc_nombre where ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Num_emp='15483' and ENT_DOCS.Status='Actual' group by ENT_PERFIL_EMP.Nombre,ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre,ENT_DOCS.Descripcion,ENT_PERFILES.Categoria,ENT_DOCS.Status,ENT_DOCS.Ultima_mod,ENT_DOCS.Revision_actual order by ENT_PERFILES.Categoria,ENT_PERFILES.Doc_nombre asc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]